# How can i configure nginx, to run apache and node js on same machine?

Tags: wordpress, node.js, apache, nginx

I am wondering how can I set up `nginx` to run both apache(lamp), and node.js on same server.

I'm not a server savy guy but the last 2 weeks I've learned a lot.

I saw that I can do content switch with `HAProxy` following : [wordpress and node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072747/wordpress-and-node-js)

however since I'm already using `nginx`  I thought it would be better to use it.

Any tutorials ? or tips ?

Comment: You [don't need both Apache and nginx](http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/apache_vs_nginx). Just use nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have single site written on PHP and you want to enable socket.io you may bind nginx on 80 port (the default HTTP port), Apache on 8080, and Node.js server on 3000 (Apache and node might have other).

Here is nginx config:

```
http {
    #... some directives ...

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {  #required for websockets
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
    }

    #... some more directives ...
}
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     your-wordpress-site.com;

    root    /path/to/site/root;
    index   index.php   index.html  index.htm;


    location / {
        try_files   $uri   $uri/  /index.php;
    }

    location /socket.io {
        proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;           #these two headers are ...
        proxy_set_header    Connection $connection_upgrade;  #...required for websockets
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
        proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Thus you only need to proxy to node when request URI starts with `/socket.io`.

I never used WordPress so I can be 100% sure that it will work without any problem on PHP side. But I configured nginx with socket.io 100K times and it always works perfectly.

**Edit**

If this configuration doesn't work, you may try change it this way:

```
location / {
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
        proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}

location /socket.io {
        #paste here socket.io section from first example
}

location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpe?g|gif)$ {
        root /path/to/site/root;
}
```

In the last `location`'s RegExp you should list all static files' extensions that you want to be served by nginx.

Comment: This helps a-lot. my intention was to have a wordpress site and have a node.js/socket.io chat plugin. the folder var/www doesnt exist on this amazon server though. and the case you described are 2 different site.

Comment: @NetaMeta edited my post. Please see changes

Comment: @NetaMeta edited one more time. Removed all redundant text

Comment: Thanks very much i am attempting it meanwhile.

Comment: Nope no luck i think my issues are even more basic then that

Comment: @NetaMeta what errors do you get? is it something like "502 Bad Gateway"?

Comment: yea got 502 bad Gateway

Comment: @NetaMeta this means that there are no service running on current port. So if you're proxying to node on `3000`, you must ensure that node right now is launched and running on `3000`

Comment: I think i have a deeper issue as i cant seem to visit ip:port or curl it at all. i get cannot access page error. and ports are opened maybe i should contact amazon.

Answer (score 1):

nginx, apache, and node.js are all their own separate servers. They are atomic entities completely independent of each other.

There are (quite common) cases where apache or nginx sits as a proxy server in front of a node.js server. So you will have two servers running on the same machine at the same time. It's important to note that they will be running on different ports.

It's very possible to have nginx, apache, and node.js all running at the same time on the same machine, but they will have to be running on different ports.

But your question "how can I set up nginx to run both apache(lamp), and node.js on same server" doesn't really make sense since nginx doesn't 'run' apache or node.js.